# JDK7 problems in windows

Tags: java, java-7

I installed JDK7 in windows. I didn't do anything more, don't confing path and classpath, this is my path enviroments:

[image]

there can find I didn't include jdk installed directory. but when I run "java -version" command in a commandline, I saw that:

[image]

but when i run "javac -version", it can't work, "javac" command undefined. If I didn't include my jdk installed directory, java and javac command must all can't work, but when in jdk7, "java" command can work, "javac" command didn't work, for solved the problem, I can include the jdk installed directory in path, but I want to know what cause the problem, is there difference between jdk7 and pre version?

Comment: The Windows Installer puts a `java.exe` into `c:\Windows\System` (or `System32` depending whether it is a 32bit or 64bit JVM). Therefor `java` is in your path, but not `javac`

Comment: Do you set JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: I suggest to use an IDE instead of doing everything manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JDK also installs a public JRE. A public JRE adds a `java.exe` stub to `\windows\system32` directory. The stub reads the registry to find out which *real* `java.exe` to execute.

Other JDK commands do not get the same treatment and require the JDK's `bin` directory to be on the system path, preferably *before* the `\windows\system32` entry, for consistency.

Comment: +1 it's amazing how some people can actually read a question before answering.

Comment: @Njol How is my answer different than this?

Comment: @KorayTugay your answer doesn't really answer the question: "I want to know what cause the problem" - the asker basically knows that there is some java.exe in one of the directories in his PATH, but no javac.exe.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a command like "javac" you should have in your path the \bin directory inside your JDK local installation

Comment: Or use the full path when compiling or writing your ant/maven/gradle/etc. scripts

Comment: Jorge_B, but why "java" command can work? it also in \bin directory and I didn't specify

Comment: As someone noted before, java.exe is usually copied into some windows directory when you install the JRE; that is probably what is working for you.  However, jdk files (like the compiler or jconsole.exe for example) are not copied there

Answer (score 0):

You probably have java.exe in Windows\system32 but not javac.

Comment: When the JDK is installed it does not place any the javac.exe in the system32 path.

Comment: I did not say it was placed there after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

`java.exe` is **also** part of the JRE whereas `javac.exe` is **only** part of the JDK

Answer (score 0):

I think what has happened is that when you installed the Environment Path that was set was pointing at the JRE bin and not the JDK bin. The JRE does not contain the javac executable. Inserting the JDK bin into the Environment Path will resolve the issue as windows will now scan that folder/location to search for the executable called javac.exe

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your java/bin directory to the PATH enviroment variable:

something like:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin